# Vector iterator loop working with g++ but not VisualC++, why?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, iterator, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a program I wrote on my linux machine. It uses a `std::vector<std::string>` and I loop over it with a for loop like so

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> words;
words.push_back("A");
words.push_back("B");
words.push_back("C");
// loop
for (auto it = words.end(); it >= words.begin(); it--)
{
    std::string word = *it; // invalid deref?
    // do things with word
    if (word == "B")
    {
        words.erase(it);
    }
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
}

int i = 0;
for (std::string word : words)
{
    std::cout << i++ << word << std::endl;
}
```

This runs as expected using g++ as the compiler, printing C, B and A. However when I run it with VisualStudio I get an invalid dereferencing exception.

I run through the vector backwards, because I want to delete items from it, and that messes with the iterator if you loop forwards.
I have a workaround using an integer and getting the items with `std::vector<std::string>.at(int)`, but I am curious why this works with my linux machine but not windows?

Comment: You are dereferencing the past-the-end iterator, undefined behavior.

Comment: Also: Why not use `rbegin` and `rend` ?

Comment: Undefined behaviour on the first loop iteration, due to dereferencing `words.end()`.   To look over a vector in reverse, use reverse iterators.

Comment: @Peter wouldn't that end up giving me the same problems as with forward looping when erasing an item in the middle of the vector?

Comment: "this runs as expected"... actually it's quite unexpected.

Comment: Are you familiar with the erase-remove idiom?

Comment: Erasing doesn't work with reverse iterators anyway.   If you want to selectively erase elements of a vector, use a forward iterator, but - when erasing an element - use the return value from `erase()` instead of incrementing.

Comment: *that messes with the iterator*: You can use the result of `erase` to get a valid iterator to not "mess up" the iterator: `it = words.erase(it);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly commented, there is an invalid dereferencing.

```
std::string word = *it;
```

Will be `std::string word = *words.end()` in the first iteration which results in undefined behaviour. So it's perfectly valid that it works on one system and throws an exception on another.

The correct way to reverse-iterate a vector would be

```
for(auto it = words.rbegin(); it != words.rend(); it++) {...}
```

However, for deleting elements from a vector, the erase-remove-idiom might be more useful:

```
words.erase(std::remove(words.begin(), words.end(), "B"), words.end());
```

Or if you have a more complex condition, use a lambda:

```
words.erase(std::remove_if(
   words.begin(), 
   words.end(), [](const std::string &name){return name == "B";}
), names.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your iteration

```
for (auto it = words.rbegin(); it != words.rend(); it++)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code invalidates the iterator in the loop by doing `words.erase(it);`. [`std::vector<>::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the `end()` iterator.

One safe way to remove a matching element is:

```
words.erase(std::remove(words.begin(), words.end(), "B"), words.end());
```

Full version:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
words.push_back("A");
words.push_back("B");
words.push_back("C");

words.erase(std::remove(words.begin(), words.end(), "B"), words.end());

int i = 0;
for (std::string word : words)
    std::cout << i++ << ' ' << word << '\n';
```